# How to find which drivers to install?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, drivers

I switched to x64 Windows 7 from my earlier x86 Windows Vista. Now I can't install drivers from the CD I got from my manufacturer. So, how should I determine which drivers I have to install? The `Device Manager` shows generic components like Monitor etc., and doesn't find the real hardware installed. I have finally gotten my video and audio to work, but my touchpad isn't working.

So what is the best way to find out the hardware my computer is actually running, and download and install drivers for them?

EDIT: Some details - I have a Dell Inspiron 1420 laptop, bought about 3 years ago. Dell's website doesn't seem to provide x-64 drivers(or those or windows 7), and I have trouble figuring out all my hardware from the configuration they have in their records. I was able to get my video card details, and then manually install the driver. But some things like touchpad, card reader are not being installed from the OEM cd or windows update and I can't figure out my hardware details.

Comment: what brand is your machine , is it a laptop ? model no ?

Comment: @Shark - I have updated the question to give more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dell does not [mention](http://support.dell.com/support/topics/global.aspx/support/kcs/document?c=us&cs=19&l=en&s=dhs&docid=DSN_364750&isLegacy=true) your model as compatible with Windows 7.
Personally i do not believe this to be true you can check out this [post](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/software-os/f/3524/p/19301913/19579706.aspx) about installing drivers from dells site which are compatible with you model .

Comment: The 2nd link turned out to be exactly what I was looking for. The author used drivers from a similar machine which was vetted for windows 7, and they worked.

Comment: +1, What Dell means is they are not going to support or provide W7 drivers on the 1420, so they dumb it down by saying it is not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you've checked out this page, but there are a few tips on the Windows site, including using Windows Update: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Update-a-driver-for-hardware-that-isnt-working-properly